# Execute Select HQL with no locks?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I have below hql query. i want to select without getting lock on tables Department, employees so that other query concurrent retrieve the records
from these table even when below query is running/executing

```
from Department dept inner join fetch dept.employees  emp where dept.Id = :DeptId
```

i tried below but thats still acquiring locks

```
from Department dept nolock inner join fetch dept.employees  emp nolock where dept.Id = :DeptId
```

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name i am using sql server.As per my understanding select will create the lock during execution of statement not for whole transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Department dept WITH(nolock) inner join fetch dept.employees  emp  where dept.Id = :DeptId
```

Try this.
Note the WITH(nolock) appended to the FROM clause.